# Well-foundedness, induction and the axiom of choice

Tags: logic, induction, axiom-of-choice

I am going through some online lecture notes which prove equivalence between:

- a relation $R$ on a set $X$ is well-founded

By which I mean: every non-empty subset of $X$ has an $R$-least element

- well-founded induction holds in $(X,R)$

By which I mean: $\big[\forall x\in X\,\big(\forall y\in X\,y\,R\,x\implies y\in P\big)\implies x\in P\big]\implies P=X$

What I am puzzled by is that one direction falls naturally: if $R$ is well-founded and $P$ some non-empty subset of $X$ such that for each $x$ and all $y\in P$ with $y\,R\,x$ we have $x\in P$ then $X\setminus P$ cannot have a least element so $X\setminus P=\emptyset$.

But the other direction requires some weak form of choice in every proof I've seen.

- are these two notions no longer equivalent in the absence of choice?
- if so, is there a reason this is often glossed over/not mentioned?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The other direction does not require any choice: you can just prove it by reversing the argument you gave.  Suppose well-founded induction holds in $(X,R)$ and let $Q$ be a subset of $X$.  If $Q$ has no least element, that means that for each $x\in Q$, there is some $y\in Q$ such that $y \mathbin{R} x$.  Letting $P=X\setminus Q$, this means that if $P$ contains all $y$ such that $y \mathbin{R} x$, then $P$ contains $x$.  So, by induction, $P=X$, so $Q$ is empty.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I know I'm being dense and that this is basic deduction, but I'm having trouble getting my head around the passage from $Q$ to $P$. So we assume that for every $x\in Q$ there is $y\in Q$ that is less-than it (wrt $R$). But then how do we arrive at $y\in P$ for all $y\,R\,x$ (and so $x\in P$ by induction)? I'm sorry if I'm being silly

Comment: It's just the contrapositive: if $x\not\in P$ (i.e., $x\in Q$), then there would have to be some $y\not\in P$ such that $y\mathbin{R} x$.

Comment: Oh of course, duh. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

No, the two are equivalent just fine without the axiom of choice.

What is true is that the Principle of Dependent Choice is equivalent to the equivalence between "$R$ is well founded" and "there are no infinite decreasing chains in $R$".

Comment: Oh I see, how would the converse be argued then? The proofs I've seen create a descending chain by inductively picking a smaller element at every step (or is that different to saying 'there is an infinite decreasing chain'?). I am confused!

Comment: Which converse exactly?